# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, connector

I know that this post is popular by finding it either on stack overflow or in stack exchange.

The problem is this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAaLT.png)

I am using C++ for creating a project that can export database from MySQL using Code::Blocks in windows 10

This is happening while I am using xampp to create a local web server environment for my Code:Blocks IDE and MySQL database. So far, I have done everything right but these are the problems that keeps popping up.

I am new with PHP and I cannot understand the reason behind the error.

I have looked over other's similar posts and  tried modifying the [config.int.PHP](https://pastebin.com/WLGVaDmb)`Php file` document. Yet, the problem still remains the same

Answer (score 0):

So this is what halped me resolve my issue, thanks to 
[Hamad Alibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13096554/hamad-alibrahim)
:

change the port number. I followed these steps and it worked for me

Port number in XAMPP can be easily changed by following this 5 steps:

step 1: stop the xampp server, if it is already running.(to avoid collapse)

step 2: run your notepad as administrator and open this 3 files:

```
xampp/properties.ini

xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

xampp/php/php.ini
```

step 3: Press ctrl+F and replace all 3306 ( port number ) with 3308(it can be anything like 3307 or 3309) .( Use ctrl+F so that you don’t miss out any 3306 port unchanged. Otherwise it won’t work)

step 4 : save all the files.

step 5 : Now restart your apache and mysql. It will work :)